# How does DllImport decide between CreateFileA and CreateFileW?

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

When I use P/Invoke for calling `CreateFile` like:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    uint dwShareMode,
    IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
    uint dwCreationDisposition,
    uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile
);
```

how does Windows decide to call `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW`?

Comment: this was based on [`CharSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/specifying-a-character-set) attribute. `CharSet.Ansi` (default value) - will be `CreateFileA`used (in your case by default), `CharSet.Unicode` - `CreateFileW` will be used

Comment: @RbMm If you have an answer you don't need to add comment, you can post an answer.

Comment: You can test it with the sample code you find here: [Specifying a Character Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/specifying-a-character-set). Using `MessageBox` (and/or `MessageBoxA`, `MessageBoxW`) with or without specifing a `CharSet`.

Comment: Isn't this documented?